# AWS Step Function - Edit using CDK or Publish completion

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have a AWS Step Function which has following steps say defined in Class A in a 3rd party package

```
- Lambda to generate a manifest file
- Sagemaker BatchTransform
- Done
```

This Step Function was defined using CDK. I have pulled in the package and would like the extend the Step Function as below

```
- Lambda to generate a manifest file
- Sagemaker BatchTransform
- Lambda to generate a marker file
- Done
```

To achieve my requirement, I tried to extend Class A but the State Machine property is defined as ReadOnly in Class A and I am not able to overwrite the property.

Another option I am looking at is publishing something like SNS message when the Step Function is completed which can trigger the lambda but I am not sure whether Step Function can publish notification using SNS.

Any suggestion on how can I edit the StepFunction using CDK or publish a notification after the Step Function is completed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new State Machine with steps as below:

- Call your first state machine (as nested step function)
- Lambda to generate a marker file
- Done